# Set tooltip on backbone marionette layout

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

How to add a tooltip on all regions and views?

Here is my layout.js:

```
  return Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
     template: bearBoxLayoutTemplate,

     regions: {
        header: ".header",
        sidebar: ".sidebar",
        workspace: ".workspace"
     },

     // onShow also didn't work
     onRender: function()
     {
        // tool tips
        $('.tooltips').tooltip();  
     }
  });
```

The code below doesn't work, but if I add the

```
  $('.tooltips').tooltip();
```

on  every view, it works. Is there any other way instead of putting the code on every view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work by listening to the show event of the regions on the initialize function of the layout

Here's the code:

```
        // listen to the region on show event
        this.sidebar.on("show", function(view){
          // manipulate the `view` or do something extra
          // with the region via `this`
          this.$el.find('.tooltips').tooltip();  
        });

        // listen to the region on show event
        this.workspace.on("show", function(view){
          // manipulate the `view` or do something extra
          // with the region via `this`
          this.$el.find('.tooltips').tooltip();  
        });
```